# Windows Service "self hosted" WCF : compression?

Tags: .net, wcf, compression

Using compression with WCF in IIS I can find documentation for, but its oriented towards using IIS features.

I can find people talking about how they've written their own compression handlers, but it all looks pretty custom.

Is there a best practice around compressing WCF? We're using http bindings.

Edit: setting this as a wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box to help you with this.

You can indeed implement your own compression extensions for WCF - several folks have done it, and you should be able to find it using your favorite search engine.

But the best thing you could do for your bindings - as long as your clients all are under your control and you can easily configure them - would be to use binary message encoding vs. textual representations of messages.

You can easily combine binary message encoding with http transport - you need a custom binding, but that's really not a big deal at all. Lots of folks have done that, too - so you can benefit from work that's already been done:

- [Binary Http Binding](https://web.archive.org/web/20150710191857/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/drnick/archive/2009/07/01/binary-http-binding.aspx) by Nicolas Allen (member of the WCF team at Microsoft)
- [Silverlight 3 WCF Binary Message Encoding](https://www.mql5.com/en/job?utm_campaign=redirect&utm_source=freelance)
- [WCF Binary Bindings in Silverlight 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20101124153904/http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/wcf-binary-bindings-in-silverlight-3/)  by John Papa (Silverlight envangelist)
- [WCF: Enable Binary Encoding Over Http](https://web.archive.org/web/20190720214523/http://jeffbarnes.net:80/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ca7287b4-f553-4c8f-bc0f-1ef68a5e420e was one that I had found, it seems as good a place to start as any. I was hoping by now there was a canned way to do this.

Comment: Well, WCF offers a lot of extensibility points, to plug those kind of things in - where and when needed.

Comment: For what it's worth, WCF 4.0 clients support GZip decompression, so you only need to build your own server compression. Server Compression will be added in the next version